# Setup LAN to serve webpages and voip and access to the web site from inside LAN with domain name

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan

I'd like to know if it will work:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dnGaost.png]

I have my domain and I'm serving a webpage in a nginx to the internet, but if I type my domain in my laptop inside LAN I access to my modem/router configuration, I cannot access to the web server unless I type the IP address. I would like to add a Bind server after the modem/router -> (port forward, ports 80 and 5060), if the request is `www.mydomain.com` bind should resolve the nginx IP address and serve it, and if it is a voip request should address to the voip server and if I'd like to access to the website from inside LAN I'd like to type `mydomain.com`. Could I do it with this configuration? Do I need something else?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this, without having to run your own bind server, is to go with a ddns provider (like noip.com) you can get a free domain or pay for one you want. Then all you do is install the update client on your webserver ( or if your router supports it, you can configure the updates on it) this will tell the noip dns server that your public ip a dress has changed. This makes your webserver internet addressable from anywhere on the interwebs to the domain of your choosing (www.mydomian.com)

As long as your port forward from your router correctly, you can set http requests to go to your webserver and voip requests to go to your voip server