# Same server address from inside and outside a LAN?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a fairly ordinary setup: A Domain Name points to my IP address and my router port-forwards specific ports to dedicated server devices inside my LAN. This allows users to access those services from the WAN.

I want my mobile users to be able to access those services from inside the LAN or outside on the WAN - *without having to reconfigure*.

(If mobile users inside the LAN use the public DNS they get my WAN-side IP address, and my router doesn't currently "hairpin" so there's no connection.)

I do have a local (caching) DNS on the LAN. So could I create a DNS entry in my LAN-side DNS that "spoofs" my own domain name and resolves the service names to the internal (non-routable) IP addresses? Is there a better way?

With VPN, could remotes tunnel into the LAN and then always use the local addresses?

([This question](https://superuser.com/questions/759556/setup-lan-to-serve-webpages-and-voip-and-access-to-the-web-site-from-inside-lan) seems similar, and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/769535/how-can-i-forward-requests-to-my-own-ip-address-to-a-local-ip-address-in-my-netw) too, but neither got an answer that works for me.)

Comment: Replace _non-routable_ by _private_ because that's something completely different; private IP addresses _can_ be routed. -- If you really can feed your local DNS cache from a local DNS server then you can try what you suggest, with a very short TTL or else your roaming users will have to wait when access changes. But it's always better to buy the right tools. In other words, if you have several roaming users, why not provide the equipment which can handle them in the way it ought to be.

Comment: You basically have two, maybe three, options here... Most corporate environments use a local corporate DNS A-record for the DNS name that resolves to the internal IP address. This is a common solution and has very little, if any, negative effects. You could also setup a DMZ that has a different subnet than your normal LAN, or allows the server to sit behind a firewall (not a router) with the public IP on directly on its interface, eliminating the need to have multiple different A-records. Or lastly, reconfigure or replace the router so hairpinning works.

Comment: Tnx, Class Stacker. I edited the question to indicate the router doesn't hairpin, but perhaps could. Is your comment about getting the right equipment based on that issue?  Is NAT loop-back, a.k.a. "Hair pinning" the best approach?  Just say so if it is.

Comment: Tnx, acejavelin, if I could hairpin the router, how does that compare/contrast with the DNS approach?

Comment: @jbbenni depends on the router and it's implementation of hairpinning, some recognize the destination IP is actually internal and just route the traffic back, some actually take the traffic to the public side, outside the firewall, and route it back like public traffic, and then some ISP gateways will route it back from the first hop gateway as well, but in all these cases the router has to handle more traffic which could be a concern for router CPU load and even bandwidth usage in some cases. The DNS route just bypasses all that and routes the traffic directly w/o use of the router.

Comment: ace - post a summary so I can acknowledge as an answer...tnx